Azure Static Web Apps, failure during content distribution
Estou tendo um problema ao tentar realizar o deploy no Azure Static Web Apps.
Deploying project to Azure Static Web Apps...
✖ Deployment Failed :(
✖ Deployment Failure Reason: Failure during content distribution.

I expected the successful deployment to be done locally via CLI

It's an issue many people, including me, are reporting here: https://github.com/Azure/static-web-apps/issues/1458 - no acknowledgement from Azure team so far.
